How to handle permissions of media files uploaded in django?
How can I handle media files securely in Django and Django REST Framework?
Basically the files should be private.
For example, suppose this is a digital product website, where the buyer will only get access to the file if they purchase the digital product. Otherwise, the product file should be private.
I can handle the permissions of DRF and Django views. But usually the media files are not private, the media files can be accessed via URL easily. If one buyer purchases and shares the file link with others everyone can download even without creating an account. So how can I handle this? Also how can I handle video files that need to be streamed to the frontend?

I think, you need to create another model for files for example DocumentModel, in here you can save to s3 storage and easyly control who can get access.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Try to do this through middleware. Using request.user, you can get the user instance and thus check these permissions.
# your_app/middleware/PermissionMiddleware.py
class PermissionMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        user = request.user

        permission = """Your code"""
        if not permission:
            raise Http404()
        return response

# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "your_app.middleware.PermissionMiddleware",
    ...
]

But remember, this will apply to all URLs, and you will need to additionally check the URLs.
